# CSS Help: Image Map and Density

Tags: jquery, css, image, dictionary, jsfiddle

I have this image map that uses CSS for a hover effect that displays information in a box. Basically, you hover over one of the map markers and then it displays information about that area of the map. It can be viewed on the link below.

http://phantasmia-online.com/world-map

Are there any CSS tricks I can use to block out the other markers when information is displayed?

Altogether, this code uses HTML, CSS, MySQL, PHP, and jQuery. For an example of this code, please look here:

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/s7cu4/4/`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at the site to get an idea of what was what, the fiddle didn't have the extra overlay.

Hopefully it doesn't break with my suggestions
You can look at the fiddle here: [Marker Show and Hide](http://jsfiddle.net/s7cu4/47/)

But I can describe my changes a bit, I removed a bit of your jquery and simplified it but I added some extra HTML

HTML:

```
<!-- Additions: class "can-hover" -->
<!-- data tag to reference the id you want to show -->
<div id="apphelmet" class="can-hover" data-seg="helmet"></div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.can-hover').on('mouseover', function(){
        //remove all can-hover
        $('.can-hover').css("display","none");

        $(this).css("display","block");
        $('#'+$(this).data("seg")).show();
    });

    $('.can-hover').on('mouseout', function(){
        //remove all can-hover
        $('.can-hover').css("display","block");
        $('#'+$(this).data("seg")).hide();
    });
});
```

All this does is wire mouse over and mouseout on each of the elements with the class can hover and it then allows it to hide the other markers and reshow them once needed.

**UPDATE:** Fixed the code to hide the segments on mouseout

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your idea is a good idea and it works but now I am having this problem where the mouseover information is not going away. Once you hover over it once, it kind of just stays there. I'm thinking it may have to do with my CSS.

Comment: Can you provide an updated fiddle so that I can test my code. I have an idea what is happening but need to test to be sure. Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/s7cu4/47/